# Simplest way to detect a Webkit browser in ASP.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, webkit

Is there a simple one-liner I can use to detect if the page request is coming from a Webkit browser? C# ASP.NET Framework 4.0

Comment: What's your motive for browser detection?

Comment: @sapph I need to programatically apply gradients to some HtmlControls. I can't add the background Style attr twice (one for FF and one for Chrome) so I need to detect the browser being used

Comment: I'd suggest just using both CSS properties in your style attribute. Sure, you are sending "useless" CSS to each browser, but I'd argue that it's easier to maintain (and more reliable) than peeking at the user agent.

Comment: @sapph I would but as far as I can tell, adding a second style attribute ('background') programmatically overwrites the previous one. So I can only have one.

Comment: @Berin what I'm saying is you can't add a second style with the same name twice programmatically. The second will overwrite the first.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC and just about every web framework I've used allows this.  I haven't used WebForms, but as long as you have a CSS stylesheet or even a style attribute, you just use a semicolon to separate the entries.  The first defined is the fallback, the second defined will be ignored if the browser doesn't recognize it.  It's the way HTML and CSS work.

Comment: @SP - What he's saying is that you don't NEED to change it programmatically, because you just define the stylesheet and use css selectors.

Comment: @Mystere - I do actually. I need to change the gradient values depending upon values known at runtime.

Comment: @SP - Well, you can still do that by changing your classnames at runtime, rather than trying to change the style.

Comment: @Mystere - Now that is a solution that would work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the HttpBrowserCapabilities.  Here is an example.

```
 System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = Request.Browser;
    string s = "Browser Capabilities\n"
        + "Type = "                    + browser.Type + "\n"
        + "Name = "                    + browser.Browser + "\n"
        + "Version = "                 + browser.Version + "\n"
        + "Major Version = "           + browser.MajorVersion + "\n"
        + "Minor Version = "           + browser.MinorVersion + "\n"
        + "Platform = "                + browser.Platform + "\n"
        + "Is Beta = "                 + browser.Beta + "\n"
        + "Is Crawler = "              + browser.Crawler + "\n"
        + "Is AOL = "                  + browser.AOL + "\n"
        + "Is Win16 = "                + browser.Win16 + "\n"
        + "Is Win32 = "                + browser.Win32 + "\n"
        + "Supports Frames = "         + browser.Frames + "\n"
        + "Supports Tables = "         + browser.Tables + "\n"
        + "Supports Cookies = "        + browser.Cookies + "\n"
        + "Supports VBScript = "       + browser.VBScript + "\n"
        + "Supports JavaScript = "     + 
            browser.EcmaScriptVersion.ToString() + "\n"
        + "Supports Java Applets = "   + browser.JavaApplets + "\n"
        + "Supports ActiveX Controls = " + browser.ActiveXControls 
              + "\n"
        + "Supports JavaScript Version = " +
            browser["JavaScriptVersion"] + "\n";
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yekbd5b.aspx